# How to allow non root user to access libvirt remotely on Centos 6

Tags: centos, ssh, remote-access, virt-manager

Default configuration according to documentation (sic!) requires root access to remote host. How to enable user access?

- [Remote management with SSH](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Administration_Guide-Remote_management_of_virtualized_guests.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found this

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-libvirt-remote-access.pkla
```

with content

```
[libvirt Management Access]    
Identity=unix-user:USER
```

And restart

```
sudo service libvirtd restart
```

Verification

```
virsh -c qemu+ssh://USER@SERVER/system sysinfo
```

Source: [How To Install KVM And libvirt On CentOS 6.2 With Bridged Networking](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on-centos-6.2-with-bridged-networking)